# [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "index.tsx" from "/app/index.html"

Tags: reactjs, flask

Here is my vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import postcssNesting from 'postcss-nesting';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    build: {
        outDir: "../backend/static",
        emptyOutDir: true,
        sourcemap: true
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
            "/ask": "http://localhost:5000",
            "/chat": "http://localhost:5000"
        }
    },
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                postcssNesting
            ],
        },
    }
});
```

and index.html contains this

`<script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>`

If i change /src/index.tsx to index.tsx,then it whines with error in the title ...

Every thread references that vite config is wrong but i do not know enough about React to figure it out ...

Many thanks for the help!

I tried what I wrote above.

edit:

```
------------------------------------
FROM node:21-alpine as node-builder

ENV APP_PATH="/app"

WORKDIR $APP_PATH
# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY app/frontend .

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install --verbose

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build
---------------------------------------


COPY --from=node-builder $APP_PATH $APP_PATH/static
```

where APP_PATH = /app

Comment: By any chance, you say you have `app/index.html`, do you also have `app/src` or just `src`?

Comment: no i do not have any of those ... i'd explain here but formatting in comments is unsupported

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering may be related to the incorrect path specified in the script tag in your HTML file. When you change the path from "/src/index.tsx" to "index.tsx," the browser is likely unable to locate the file. To resolve this issue, make sure to provide the correct path based on the structure of your project.

Assuming that your index.tsx file is in the "src" directory, you should use a relative path like this:

```
<script type="module" src="./src/index.tsx"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default Vite js template then the main `index.tsx` file is created in `src` directory and their diclarations are setup based on the main file location.

If you want to change the path of your script then you have to create `index.tsx` file in you project root directory with appropriate rendering.

Comment: thanks, any idea how can i do that?

Comment: But what is the reason that you need to change the path of you file? I mean is there any special purpose that you have to come up with?

Comment: i rewrote my dockerfile and apparently it's a bit different than before ... the original project used devcontainers and vscode and i don't use that ...

Answer (score 0):

Ah i got it, i think ...

in vite config, build dir needs to be relative:

```
outDir: "dist",
```

and then in dockerfile, i copy the contents of the built folder  like so:

```
COPY --from=node-builder $APP_PATH/dist $APP_PATH/static
```

and then flask needs this route

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

No changes needed in index.html .... in fact, build process fails with any
change i make in there ...

Anyway, flask now serves both react and python apps